# Cant get Opencv C++ to run on M1 Visual Code

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, visual-studio-code, apple-m1

After days on working on this problem on my M1 studio, training to figure out, I got all these things correct on visual Code, but nothing worked, it will hang and never run; if I use Cmake, it will compile, but for debugging I could never get it to Run.

Meaning it will Run, but to will hang on my M1, everything worked fine, but could not debug code on MS Visual Code using OpenCV C++

Comment: please decide: xcode? visual *studio* code? visual studio?

Comment: welcome. [mre] required. you also haven't got the "informed" badge yet, so please also take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Then I realized that I was trying to use Microsoft Software with Apple M1 and then installed XCODE, and everything worked great!!! And I love it!!!

And most important of all, **I AM not using homeBrew!!!**

1.- under "headers," I added /usr/local/include/opencv4
2.- under libraries, I added /usr/local/lib
3.- then I added the link libraries: libopencv_core.dylib, libopencv_imgproc.dylib, libopencv_highgui.dylib, libopencv_imgcodecs.dylib, libopencv_videoio.dylib.

So beautiful!!!! I was able to compile and debug my code, with break points and everything.

Here is my files for visual Code, for anyone:

tasks.json

```
"tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-std=c++17",
                "-stdlib=libc++",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "-I/usr/local/include/opencv4/**",
                "-L/usr/local/lib",
                "-lopencv_core",
                "-lopencv_highgui",
                "-lopencv_imgcodecs",               
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",            
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

c_cpp_properties.jason

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/local/include/opencv4/**",
                "/usr/local/lib"              
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: OT: `"${file}",` would be a problem if you have more than 1 cpp file used in your application. I mention this because it's a very common problem for new people to VSCode.